# Converting pandas dataframe to dict (timestamp->datetime conversions)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `dt`. When I do `df.to_dict(orient="records")`, the type of the `dt` column values get converted to a pandas timestamp in the dict entries.

So I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {col: val.to_pydatetime() if isinstance(val, pd.Timestamp) else val for col, val in row.items()}
    for row in df.to_dict(orient='records')
]
```

Is there a better/innate way to do this conversion during the `to_dict` op?

Comment: so your goal is to have vanilla Python datetime objects in the output?

Comment: @FObersteiner right

Answer (score 0):

Pandas doesn't provide a built-in parameter in `to_dict()` to control the serialization of dates, but you can control the datetime conversion when calling `to_json()`, which allows for more customization regarding datetime formatting. This can be useful if you want to convert the dataframe to a JSON-like format and still have control over how datetimes are handled.

Comment: json has no datetime type; a datetime will be just a string or a number. [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) only allows you to chose from ISO format or Unix timestamp - which is very reasonable since json should not contain arbitrarily formatted datetime for interoperability reasons.